# select data where two column have the same data in two different tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables, and they have three column in common as shown below:

table 1

| x | id2 | id3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 |

table 2

| y | id2 | id3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 0 | 1 |

for example I want to get data from table one where the two columns id2 and id3 have the same value as table 2,

so the result would be like this:

| x | id2 | id3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

It is simple join

```
select t1.*
  from t1 join t2 on t1.id2 = t2.id2 and t1.id3 = t2.id3
```

Comment: I tried this code but it return nothing if the id3 column is empty in table 1

Answer (score 0):

It is another view you are looking for a filter table. You want to select some data based on defined in table 2.

Let's assume table 2 is your filter, and you can find data basically join or just select

```
select * from table1 t1.*
left join table2 t2 on t2.id2 = t1.id2 and t2.id3 = t1.id3
```